# Показать/скрыть DIV с помощью радиокнопок

Tags: jquery

Я совсем новичок в JS, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Есть три разных DIV-блока, каждый из которых "привязан" к одной из трех радиокнопок. Мне нужно, чтобы содержание на странице менялось при изменении выбора в группе радиокнопок. Изначально на странице должен отображаться первый DIV-блок, и должна быть выбрана первая радиокнопка (т.е. состояние "checked"). При выборе другой радиокнопки этот DIV-блок должен быть скрыт и показан блок, соответствующий выбранной радиокнопке.

```js
$('#idregions').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#timeline').hide();
    $('#countries').hide();
    $('#regions').show();
  }
}).trigger('change');

$('#idcountries').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#timeline').hide();
    $('#regions').hide();
    $('#countries').show();
  }
}).trigger('change');

$('#idtimeline').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#countries').hide();
    $('#regions').hide();
    $('#timeline').show();
  }
}).trigger('change');

$(function() {
  $("#idregions").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $("#idcountries, #idtimeline").prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#idcountries").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $("#idregions, #idtimeline").prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#idtimeline").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $("#idcountries, #idregions").prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" id="idregions" class="label09" name=rl  checked="checked"/>regions</label>
<label><input type="radio" id="idcountries" class="label09" name=rl/>countries</label>
<label><input type="radio" id="idtimeline" class="label09" name=rl/>trip</label>


<div id="regions">1</div>
<div id="countries">2</div>
<div id="timeline">3</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Помогите разобраться, как это сделать.

Comment: Ваш код рабочий после подключения `jquery.min.js`. В чем суть вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

Ниже сокращенный аналог вашего кода (потому что, зачем переключать радио через скрипт, если эта функция и так встроена в них).

В данном случае радиокнопки несут исключительно декоративный характер. Хотяя... их можно переключать через стрелки на клавиатуре, что тоже плюс.

```js
$('.bubu').on('click', function(){
  $('.tab').hide();
 
  var index = $('.bubu').index( $(this) ); 
  // Находим номер элемента this, среди классов bubu.
  // Т.к. кнопок и вкладок - одинаковое кол-во, по этому же номеру можно показать вкладку
  $('.tab').eq(index).show();
});
```

```css
.tab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="bubu"><input type="radio" name="rl" checked>regions</label>
<label class="bubu"><input type="radio" name="rl">countries</label>
<label class="bubu"><input type="radio" name="rl">trip</label>

<div class="tab" style="display: block;">1</div>
<div class="tab">2</div>
<div class="tab">3</div>
```

[JavaScript переключаемые вкладки - табы (и немного CSS)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981934/javascript-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-css/982073#982073) - во втором пункте есть похожий пример.

Comment: Супер! Спасибо, воспользовался тем, что по ссылке